# How to check javascript nested objects for existence (avoid "undefined is not an object" errors)

Tags: javascript, error-handling

We have the following snippet of code:

```
if (err.response.data.msg) {
    setError(err.response.data.msg);
    setTimeout(() => setError(null), 4000);
}
```

Which throws an error when any of `err`, or `err.response`, or `err.response.data` are null or undefined. We could replace this with:

```
if (err && err.response && err.response.data && err.response.data.msg) {
    setError(err.response.data.msg);
    setTimeout(() => setError(null), 4000);
}
```

Is this the best way to avoid the errors thrown when any of these values are null or undefined? Or is there a more generally accepted approach in Javascript / React for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the null safety operator `?` and check:

```
if (err?.response?.data?.msg) {
    setError(err.response.data.msg);
    setTimeout(() => setError(null), 4000);
}
```

This will avoid any errors getting thrown and still make sure the value you are looking for actually exists.